# Is there any good reason for choosing useReducer instead of useState if I use useState with a partial update callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to rewrite my app using hooks (useState, useReducer, useEffect, etc). And actually I use useReducer a lot, but still want to understand places where it will be not possible to useState, but useReducer, e.g. in this simple dummy code snippet:

```js
// Setting initial state
const [state, useState] = React.useState({a: 1, b: 2})


// Update only a piece of state (the same as old this.setState({c: 3}))
setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    c: 3
}))

setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    d: 4
}))

setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    a: 100
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible to use `useState()` but when you use `useReducer()`, you can extract state update logic into actions/reducer to simplify your component:

```js
const Component = () => {
// Setting initial state
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {a: 1, b: 2})


// Update only a piece of state (the same as old this.setState({c: 3}))
dispatch(setC(3));
dispatch(setD(4));
dispatch(setA(100));
```